# getCollection on Custom Model return false <=> 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9

I have some problems with my custom modul.

This is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Mymodule_Marques>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
    </Mymodule_Marques>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <marques>
            <class>Mymodule_Marques_Block</class>
        </marques>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <marques>
            <class>Mymodule_Marques_Helper</class>
        </marques>
    </helpers>
    <models>
        <marques>
            <class>Mymodule_Marques_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>mymodule_marques_resource</resourceModel>
        </marques>
        <mymodule_marques_resource>
            <class>Mymodule_Marques_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <marque>
                    <table>mymodule_marques</table>
                </marque>
            </entities>
        </mymodule_marques_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <marques_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Mymodule_Marques</module>
            </setup>
        </marques_setup>
        <mymodule_marques_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </mymodule_marques_read>
        <mymodule_marques_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </mymodule_marques_write>
    </resources>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <marques>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mymodule_Marques</module>
                <frontName>marques</frontName>
            </args>
        </marques>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <marques>
                <file>marques.xml</file>
            </marques>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

this is my controller

```
<?php

class Mymodule_Marques_Adminhtml_MarquesController extends 
Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

public function _initAction() {
    $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('cms');
    return $this;
}

public function indexAction() {
    $this->_title(Mage::helper('marques')->__('Choose store'));

    $this->_initAction()
            ->renderLayout();
    return;
}

public function clickAction() {
    $this->_title(Mage::helper('marques')->__('choose brands'));

    $this->_initAction()
            ->renderLayout();
    return;
}


public function editAction() {
    $this->_title(Mage::helper('marques')->__('edit brands'));

    $this->_initAction()
            ->renderLayout();
    return;
}


}
```

in my folder Block/Adminhtml , i create new folder Edit with this files: 
Tabs.php =>

```
<?php

class Mymodule_Marques_Block_Adminhtml_Edit_Tabs extends 
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('marques_tabs');
    $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
}

protected function _beforeToHtml() {
  $cpt = 0;
    $blocks = Mage::helper("marques")->getBlocks(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam("store_id"));

    if($blocks){
        foreach ($blocks as $block) {
            $cpt++;
            $this->addTab('block_'.$cpt, array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('marques')->__('Block '.$cpt),
                'title' => Mage::helper('marques')->__('Block '.$cpt),
                'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('marques/adminhtml_edit_tab_block')->setBlockNumber($cpt)->setBlock($block)->toHtml(),
            ));
        }
    }
    while ($cpt < 3) {
        $cpt++;
        $this->addTab('block_'.$cpt, array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('marques')->__('Block '.$cpt),
            'title' => Mage::helper('marques')->__('Block '.$cpt),
            'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('marques/adminhtml_edit_tab_block')->setBlockNumber($cpt)->toHtml(),
        ));
    }
}

}
```

this is my file Form.php

```
<?php

class Mymodule_Marques_Block_Adminhtml_Edit_Form extends 
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

protected function _prepareForm() {
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
            'id' => 'edit_form',
            'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
            'method' => 'post',
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
        )
    );

    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}

}
```

Abd i create a new folder in Edit, this name is Tab with file Block.php

```
<?php

class Mymodule_Marques_Block_Adminhtml_Edit_Tab_Block extends 
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form implements 
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface {

protected function _prepareForm() {
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('block_'.$this->getBlockNumber().'_fieldset', array('legend' => Mage::helper('marques')->__("Block ".$this->getBlockNumber())));

    if ($this->getBlock()) {
        $fieldset->addField('marques_id', 'hidden', array(
            'name' => 'block['.$this->getBlockNumber().'][marques_id]'
        ));
        $fieldset->addField('store_id', 'hidden', array(
            'name' => 'block['.$this->getBlockNumber().'][store_id]',
        ));
    }else{
        $fieldset->addField('store_id', 'hidden', array(
            'name' => 'block['.$this->getBlockNumber().'][store_id]',
            'value' => Outdoordiffusion_Home_Model_Home_Type::TYPE_TROISBLOCS
        ));
        $fieldset->addField('type', 'hidden', array(
            'name' => 'block['.$this->getBlockNumber().'][type]',
            'value' => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam("store_id")
        ));
    }

    $fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('marques')->__('Image'),
        'name' => 'block'.$this->getBlockNumber().'_image',
        'required' => true,
        'note'  => $this->__("Dimensions : 376px x 218px.")
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('label', 'text', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('home')->__('Label'),
        'name' => 'block['.$this->getBlockNumber().'][label]',
        'required' => true,
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('url', 'text', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('marques')->__('Url'),
        'name' => 'block['.$this->getBlockNumber().'][url]',
        'required' => true,
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('position', 'text', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('marques')->__('Position'),
        'name' => 'block['.$this->getBlockNumber().'][position]',
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('onclick', 'text', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('marques')->__('Onclick'),
        'name' => 'block['.$this->getBlockNumber().'][onclick]',
        'note' => $this->__("Exemple : ga('send', 'event', 'event1', 'event1', 'event1');")
    ));



    if ($this->getBlock()) {
        $form->setValues($this->getBlock()->getData());
    }

    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}

public function getTabLabel() {
    return Mage::helper('marques')->__('Block '.$this->getBlockNumber());
}

public function getTabTitle() {
    return Mage::helper('marques')->__('Block '.$this->getBlockNumber());
}

public function canShowTab() {
    return true;
}

public function isHidden() {
    return false;
}

}
```

This my file marques.xml in design/adminhtml/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<marques_adminhtml_marques_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="marques/adminhtml_store" name="marques_store" />
    </reference>
</marques_adminhtml_marques_index>
 <marques_adminhtml_marques_click>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="marques/adminhtml_click_marques" name="marques_grid" />
    </reference>
</marques_adminhtml_marques_click>
<marques_adminhtml_marques_edit>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="marques/adminhtml_edit_tabs" name="marques_edit_tabs" />
    </reference>
</marques_adminhtml_marques_edit>
</layout>
```

And this is my helper how call my model marque

```
<?php

class Mymodule_Marques_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {


 public function getBlocks($storeId = null){

    $blocks = Mage::getModel("marques/marque")->getCollection();

    var_dump($blocks);

    echo get_class(Mage::getModel('marques/marque'));exit;


}



}
```

this is my MODEL with file marque and folder Resource and collection.php

```
<?php

class Mymodule_Marques_Model_Marque extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

public function _construct() {

    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('mymodule_marques/marque');

}

}
```

this is my resource

```
<?php

 class Mymodule_Marques_Model_Resource_Marque extends 
 Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
 {
 public function _construct() {

    $this->_init('mymodule_marques/marque', 'marques_id');

 }
 }
```

and this is my collection

```
<?php

 class Mymodule_Marques_Model_Resource_Marque_Collection extends 
 Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
 {
 protected  function _construct() {     

    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('mymodule_marques/marque');

 }
  }
```

In my admin i have an errors this =>

$blocks = Mage::getModel("marques/marque")->getCollection(); 
return false

Can you help , what I do not see ????

Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not posted the Model, ResourceModel & Collection files. Do you have them in place or not ? If not, you have to create them in order to use collection.

**Updated Answer**

Change your Model file like this

```
<?php

class Mymodule_Marques_Model_Marque extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

public function _construct() {

    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('marques/marque');

}

}
```

Change your ResourceModel file like this

```
<?php

 class Mymodule_Marques_Model_Resource_Marque extends 
 Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
 {
 public function _construct() {

    $this->_init('marques/marque', 'marques_id');

 }
 }
```

Change your Collection file like this

```
<?php

 class Mymodule_Marques_Model_Resource_Marque_Collection extends 
 Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
 {
 protected  function _construct() {     

    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('marques/marque');

 }
  }
```